# Authorization header returns 405 error, React, CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, reactjs, axios

I recently setup a React application with a CodeIgniter backend serving as the API. To use a token pre-set, I setup an `axios` instance as follows

```
axiosInstance() {
    const token = this.getWebToken();

    let instance = () => {
        return axios.create({
            baseURL: Constants.app.BASE_API_URL,
            headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
        });
    };

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(instance());
    });
}
```

Later on, I call this instance as follows

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const endpoint = `${Constants.app.BASE_API_URL}/test/base_url`;

    this.apiService.axiosInstance()
        .then(axios_instance => {
            return axios_instance.post(endpoint)
        })
        .then(response => resolve(response.data))
        .catch(error => reject(error));
});
```

The PHP file (Codeigniter) has the following headers set

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, Authorization");
```

This returns a 405: Method not allowed error. I tested it in Postman without the Authorization header and it worked fine. I took out the Authorization header as well here and it worked, but I will like to use the authorization header. Any help?
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');